# Is it possible to authenticate using whatsapp?

Tags: android, authentication, whatsapp, mobile-application

Is there a whatsapp authentication like Google, Facebook and many others does.
I need to authenticate a user using there whatsapp number. More over all, it is all about getting whatsapp number of a user.

Comment: Nice concept, but currently even whatsapp verifies the number by text message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, you can't Whatsapp has not exposed any authentication API.

There are only two ways to integrate with WhatsApp: - Through a custom URL scheme - Through Android's intent system.

[Check I'm an Android developer, how can I integrate WhatsApp with my app?](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012)

Comment: do you think we can get the registered whatsapp number ?.

Comment: No... i donot think we can get registered whatsapp number.